# Cardinality of a field between interval

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

I was studying for an exam when I came across the following question:

> Let $F$ a field such that $4<|F|<15$. The number of elements in $F$ is:
>   A. 6 or 7
>   B. 11 or 13
>   C. 8 or 9
>   D. 7 or 14

For better understanding of the problem, I defined $|x|=|F|, x \in \mathbb{R}$

Then, after some calculations, I found that $|x|=11$, but I can't understand why there is 2 possible sizes for this field.

Why would the cardinality of $F$ be two different numbers? Is it possible?

Comment: Both B and C are possible, since a finite field has order a prime power.

Comment: How did you find that $|x|=11$?

Comment: I used the modulus properties for inequalities. Got to thinking, the answer was more than obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is asking what cardinalities are possible for $F$ to have without any further information being given. The reason for this is that a finite field has as its order the power of some prime number, i.e., $p^n$ for some prime $p$ and $n\geq 1$. The only such numbers between $4$ and $15$ are those in options B and C.

However, all options listed in B and C are possible: there exists a finite field of size $8$, but also one of $9$, or one of $11$, or one of size $13$ (actually, only one for each size, up to isomorphism).

So I think this is a bad question, unless multiple answers were allowed...

Comment: I think this is a bad question even if multiple answers were allowed.

Comment: It helped me understand both the question and the "solution". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information given, we cannot conclude the precise order of  $F $. A useful hint is that the order of a finite field $F$ is $p^n $ ,where $p$ is the characteristic of  $F$(and it's a prime).

Comment: "limited information given"? I transcribed the question from an old exam. Maybe it is wrong, or poorly described?

Comment: Please, @PrincipiantForever, never think that there may not be infelicities, or even rank errors in an examination. The people who write examinations are not gods, but all-too-fallible human beings. I shudder to think of all the errors I committed, both large and small, in the exams I wrote when I was teaching.

Comment: @PrincipiantForever The question is poorly described.

Comment: @Lubin you can't be more right about it. Unfortunately, I believe this causes great impact on students lives.